# Sql request with case when select

Tags: sql

My SQL request is not working even if i tried different solutions.

I got a table `TableOne` with a list of items with rows like this

```
A 
B 
C.
```

I have another table `TableTwo` with a list of items with rows like this

```
A a
A b
A c
B a
B d
B e
C f
```

I would like to extract the lines and i need to know if one specific value is present in the second table (for example, the value a)

Something like this :

```
A yes
B yes
C no
```

Here my request :

```
SELECT 
    a.letter,                                               
    CASE
       WHEN a.letter IN (SELECT e.letter FROM TableTwo e WHERE e.text = 'SAIRET') 
          THEN 'yes'
          ELSE 'no'
    END
FROM 
    TableOne a                                                 
INNER JOIN
    TableTwo e ON a.letter = e.letter
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
SELECT a.letter,
Case
    WHEN b.letter is null then 'No'
    ELSE 'Yes'
END AS [Check]
FROM
a
LEFT JOIN
b
ON a.letter = b.letter
```

Firstly, inner join only keeps rows that are present in both tables. So you will never get result 'No' on that test

Answer (score 0):

What is e.text in your second table ? Please provide more detailed scenario ? If that is not present. Below is the the query.

```
Select  a.letter,
Case when b.letter is not null then 'YES' else 'NO' End as flg
From tableone a 
Left join tabletwo b on a.letter =b.letter;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must join the tables, `group by letter` and use conditional aggregation:

```
select 
  t1.letter,
  case 
    when sum(case t2.text when 'a' then 1 end) > 0 then 'yes'
    else 'no'
  end result
from tableone t1 left join tabletwo t2
on t2.letter = t1.letter
group by t1.letter
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q14hGeWgaXZg92Q6E52dEi/0).
Results:

```
| letter | result |
| ------ | ------ |
| A      | yes    |
| B      | yes    |
| C      | no     |
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.
It is perfectly working!

Comment: @ClarisseBADIOU if this solved your problem consider accepting the answer by ticking the checkmark at the left.

Answer (score 0):

If `tabletwo` has all the letters that are in `tableone`, then you can just use conditional aggregation:

```
select t2.letter,
       (case when sum(case when t2.text = 'SAIRET' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 'yes' else 'no'
        end)
from tabletwo t2
group by t2.letter;
```

Otherwise, I would recommend `exists`:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from tabletwo t2
                          where t2.letter = t.letter and t2.text = 'SAIRET'
                         )
             then 1 else 0
        end)
from tableone t1;
```

This should be the fastest method, particularly with an index on `tabletwo(letter, text)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for all your answers

It is working with the following request

case when sum(case e.actio1 when 'SAIRET' then 1 end) >0 then 'oui'
else 'non' end

Comment: Take some time and read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers/251399#251399 so you know how things work here in SO.